# Can someone explain the axiom of separation for ZF Set Theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-theory

I'm studying ZF Set Theory now and my brain is about to explode. I have 2 questions:

1. I dont understand the axiom of separation. What exactly is a formula $\phi(x)$?

Definition in my notes: For each set A and each formula φ(x), there is a set whose elements are exactly those x in A such that φ(x) holds.

2. What is an **axiom schema**?

Comment: One way to think about is that logical formulas in a way are "constraints" on the space of total ideas. It specifices somethings out of them. So, here they are saying is that whatever logic formula you use to constrain this space, you can always get out of a set. For axiom schema check wikipedia.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer them in reverse order.

What is an axiom schema? Well, a single axiom is a single property that we would like our universe of sets to have. For example, the axiom of infinity asserts that there exists at least one infinite set. However, the axiom of separation is not a single axiom -- there are infinitely many axioms, one for each possible formula. Maybe it's best to replace "schema" with "template". For every formula $\phi$, we make an axiom using this template and add it to our theory.

What is a formula? Well, there are some rules for what formulas look like and the symbols they contain, you can find them here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula. Here's a famous example: let $\phi(x) = \neg (x \in x)$. $\phi(x)$ being true means that "$x$ does not contain itself". Given a set $A$ and this formula $\phi$, the axiom scheme of separation (for $\phi$) guarantees there exists a subset $B \subset A$ of all elements $x \in A$ that do not contain themselves.